# create android java file from native code

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to write android java file for the native code given below.
I have loaded the file using system.loadLibrary(). What changes i should make to activity file?
The openCL part is not a problem as I am having the libraries for it.

```
#include <FrmPlatform.h>
#include <FrmComputeApplication.h>
#include <FrmUtils.h>
#include <OpenCL/FrmKernel.h>
#include "Compute.h"


    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Name: FrmCreateApplicationInstance()
    // Desc: Global function to create the application instance
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    CFrmComputeApplication* FrmCreateComputeApplicationInstance()
    {
        return new CSample( "VectorAdd" );
    }


    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Name: CSample()
    // Desc: Constructor
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    CSample::CSample( const CHAR* strName ) : CFrmComputeApplication( strName )
    {
        m_commandQueue = 0;
        m_program = 0;
        m_kernel = 0;
        m_srcA = 0;
        m_srcB = 0;
        m_result = 0;
        m_nNumVectors = 1024;
    }


    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Name: Initialize()
    // Desc:
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    BOOL CSample::Initialize()
    {
        cl_int errNum;

        if(!FrmOpenConsole())
            return FALSE;

        // Create the command queue
        m_commandQueue = clCreateCommandQueue( m_context, m_devices[0], CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE, &errNum );
        if ( errNum != CL_SUCCESS )
        {
            FrmLogMessage( "Failed to create command queue" );
            return FALSE;
        }

        if( FALSE == FrmBuildComputeProgramFromFile( "Samples/Kernels/VectorAdd.cl", &m_program, m_context,
                                                      &m_devices[0], 1, "-cl-fast-relaxed-math" ) )
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Create kernel
        m_kernel = clCreateKernel( m_program, "VectorAdd", &errNum );
        if ( errNum != CL_SUCCESS )
        {
            FrmLogMessage( "Failed to create kernel 'VectorAdd'\n" );
            return FALSE;
        }

         // Create device buffers
        m_srcA = clCreateBuffer( m_context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, m_nNumVectors * sizeof(FRMVECTOR4), NULL, &errNum );
        if( errNum != CL_SUCCESS )
        {
            FrmLogMessage( "ERROR: allocation device host buffer A" );
            return FALSE;
        }

        m_srcB = clCreateBuffer( m_context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, m_nNumVectors * sizeof(FRMVECTOR4), NULL, &errNum );
        if( errNum != CL_SUCCESS )
        {
            FrmLogMessage( "ERROR: allocation device host buffer B" );
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Map to host arrys
        FRMVECTOR4 *pHostA = (FRMVECTOR4*) clEnqueueMapBuffer( m_commandQueue, m_srcA, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_WRITE, 0, sizeof(FRMVECTOR4) * m_nNumVectors,
                                                               0, NULL, NULL, &errNum );
        if( errNum != CL_SUCCESS )
        {
            FrmLogMessage( "ERROR: mapping device buffer A." );
            return FALSE;
        }

        FRMVECTOR4 *pHostB = (FRMVECTOR4*) clEnqueueMapBuffer( m_commandQueue, m_srcB, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_WRITE, 0, sizeof(FRMVECTOR4) * m_nNumVectors,
                                                               0, NULL, NULL, &errNum );
        if( errNum != CL_SUCCESS )
        {
            FrmLogMessage( "ERROR: mapping device buffer B." );
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Fill with data
        for( size_t i = 0; i < m_nNumVectors; i++ )
        {
            FLOAT32 valA = (FLOAT32)i / m_nNumVectors;
            FLOAT32 valB = 1.0f - valA;
            pHostA[i] = FRMVECTOR4( valA, valA, valA, valA );
            pHostB[i] = FRMVECTOR4( valB, valB, valB, valB );
        }



        // Compute reference results on CPU
        if ( RunTests() )
        {
            m_pRefResults = new FRMVECTOR4[ m_nNumVectors ];
            for( size_t i = 0; i < m_nNumVectors; i++ )
            {
                m_pRefResults[ i ] = pHostA[ i ] + pHostB[ i ];
            }
        }

        // Unmap buffers
        errNum = clEnqueueUnmapMemObject( m_commandQueue, m_srcA, pHostA, 0, NULL, NULL );
        if( errNum != CL_SUCCESS )
        {
            FrmLogMessage( "ERROR: Unmapping buffer A." );
            return FALSE;
        }

        errNum = clEnqueueUnmapMemObject( m_commandQueue, m_srcB, pHostB, 0, NULL, NULL );
        if( errNum != CL_SUCCESS )
        {
            FrmLogMessage( "ERROR: Unmapping buffer B." );
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Create result buffer
        m_result = clCreateBuffer( m_context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, m_nNumVectors * sizeof(FRMVECTOR4), NULL, &errNum );
        if( errNum != CL_SUCCESS )
        {
            FrmLogMessage( "ERROR: allocation device host buffer result" );
            return FALSE;
        }
        return TRUE;
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Name: Destroy()
    // Desc:
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    VOID CSample::Destroy()
    {
        if( m_commandQueue != 0 )
        {
            clReleaseCommandQueue( m_commandQueue );
            m_commandQueue = 0;
        }

        if( m_program != 0 )
        {
            clReleaseProgram( m_program );
            m_program = 0;
        }

        if( m_kernel != 0 )
        {
            clReleaseKernel( m_kernel );
            m_kernel = 0;
        }

        if( m_srcA != 0 )
        {
            clReleaseMemObject( m_srcA );
            m_srcA = 0 ;
        }

        if( m_srcB != 0 )
        {
            clReleaseMemObject( m_srcB );
            m_srcB = 0;
        }

        if( m_result != 0 )
        {
            clReleaseMemObject( m_result );
            m_result = 0;
        }

        delete [] m_pRefResults;
    }



    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Name: Compute()
    // Desc:
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    BOOL CSample::Compute()
    {
        m_Timer.Reset();
        m_Timer.Start();

        char str[256];

        // Set the kernel arguments
        cl_int errNum = 0;
        errNum |= clSetKernelArg( m_kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &m_srcA );
        errNum |= clSetKernelArg( m_kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &m_srcB );
        errNum |= clSetKernelArg( m_kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &m_result );
        if( errNum != CL_SUCCESS )
        {
            FrmLogMessage( "Error setting kernel arguments" );
            return FALSE;
        }

        size_t globalWorkSize[1] = { m_nNumVectors };
        size_t localWorkSize[1] = { 1 };

        cl_event kernel_event;
        cl_ulong t_queued=0, t_submit=0, t_start=0, t_end=0;

        // Queue the kernel for execution
        errNum = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel( m_commandQueue, m_kernel, 1, NULL,
                                        globalWorkSize, localWorkSize, 0, NULL, &kernel_event );
        if( errNum != CL_SUCCESS )
        {
            FrmLogMessage( "Error queueing kernel for execution." );
            return FALSE;
        }

        clWaitForEvents(1 , &kernel_event);

        // Query timestamp for kernel profiling
        //   Queued time is when the command is queued to host.
        //   Submit time is when the command is submitted from host to device.
        //   Start time is when the command starts the execution.
        //   End time is when the command finishes the execution.
        // The delta between start and end, marks the total elapsed time to execute a kernel in device.
        errNum = clGetEventProfilingInfo(kernel_event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_QUEUED,
                    sizeof(cl_ulong), &t_queued, NULL);
        if( errNum != CL_SUCCESS ) FrmLogMessage( "Error getting queued timestamp." );
        errNum = clGetEventProfilingInfo(kernel_event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_SUBMIT,
                    sizeof(cl_ulong), &t_submit, NULL);
        if( errNum != CL_SUCCESS ) FrmLogMessage( "Error getting submit timestamp." );
        errNum = clGetEventProfilingInfo(kernel_event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START,
                    sizeof(cl_ulong), &t_start,    NULL);
        if( errNum != CL_SUCCESS ) FrmLogMessage( "Error getting start timestamp." );
        errNum = clGetEventProfilingInfo(kernel_event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END,
                    sizeof(cl_ulong), &t_end, NULL);
        if( errNum != CL_SUCCESS ) FrmLogMessage( "Error getting end timestamp." );

        FrmLogMessage("Kernel event profiling....(nano sec)\n");
        FrmSprintf(str, sizeof(str), "  -> Queued time: %lu\n", t_queued);
        FrmLogMessage( str );
        FrmSprintf(str, sizeof(str), "  -> Submit time: %lu\n", t_submit);
        FrmLogMessage( str );
        FrmSprintf(str, sizeof(str), "  -> Start time:  %lu\n", t_start);
        FrmLogMessage( str );
        FrmSprintf(str, sizeof(str), "  -> End time:    %lu\n", t_end);
        FrmLogMessage( str );

        clReleaseEvent(kernel_event);

        // Read the result back to host memory
        FRMVECTOR4* pResult;
        pResult = (FRMVECTOR4*) clEnqueueMapBuffer( m_commandQueue, m_result, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ, 0, sizeof(FRMVECTOR4) * m_nNumVectors,
                                                    0, NULL, NULL, &errNum );
        if( errNum != CL_SUCCESS )
        {
            FrmLogMessage( "Error enqueuing buffer map." );
            return FALSE;
        }
        m_Timer.Stop();

        FrmSprintf( str, sizeof(str), "Results: '%d' vector additions in '%.6f' seconds.\n", m_nNumVectors, m_Timer.GetTime() );
        FrmLogMessage( str );

        // Test results again CPU reference
        BOOL result = TRUE;
        if ( RunTests() )
        {
            const FLOAT32 epsilon = 0.000001f;

            for( size_t i = 0; i < m_nNumVectors; i++ )
            {
                for ( size_t j = 0; j < 4; j++ )
                {
                    FLOAT32 refVal = m_pRefResults[ i ].v[ j ];
                    FLOAT32 val = pResult[ i ].v[ j ];

                    if( FrmAbs( refVal - val ) > epsilon )
                    {
                        FrmSprintf( str, sizeof(str), "Reference test failure, ref = (%f), result = (%f) Diff = (%f).\n", refVal, val, FrmAbs(refVal - val));
                        FrmLogMessage( str );
                        result = FALSE;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        // Unmap buffer
        errNum = clEnqueueUnmapMemObject( m_commandQueue, m_result, pResult, 0, NULL, NULL );
        if( errNum != CL_SUCCESS )
        {
            FrmLogMessage( "ERROR: Unmapping result buffer." );
            return FALSE;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put system.loadLibrary() in the static section of a java class, for example ExampleJNILib class.

Define the native functions in ExampleJNILib class.
Define the JNI interface in C code, which will bridge the JAVA class ExampleJNILib and your native C code.

Then in the activity class, call the native function directly when you need it.

You can actually check the NDK example, hello-jni or hello-gl2. These are pretty good examples, and should fit into your case.

Comment: Or to explain a bit, you can't generally call *arbitrary* native code from Java.  Instead, you will have to construct some native glue methods that are jni-compatible, and have those call your existing native methods.